# Can't install Find My iPhone app on iPhone 4 as it requires iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, find-my-iphone

I reset my iPhone 4 as I gave it to a friend. I am unable to install Find My iPhone as prompt says I need iOS 8 to run this app. What can I do? I know iOS 8 is not available for iPhone 4, but apps should work for the last version of iOS released for the iPhone 4, iOS 7.1.2. What can I do to get this app downloaded or this is a lost cause?

Comment: You can download apps directly in iTunes without your phone connected. Then on your phone, launch the App Store and go to the Purchased page via the Updates tab. Try installing the app. Your device will notify you that the current version of the app requires iOS 7 or later. Then, it will offer you the option to install a previous version that is compatible with the iPhone you are holding. - taken from http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/installing-apps-older-version-ios/

Answer (score 2):

When attempting to download an app that has been updated and no longer supports an older version of iOS, you will receive the following prompt:

> **Download an older version of this app?**
>
> The current version requires iOS 8.0 or later, but you can download the last compatible version.
>
> Cancel | **Download**

Tapping Download will download the last version of the app compatible with the version of iOS you are running.

Comment: "Tapping Download will download the last version of the app compatible with the version of iOS you are running." --this only happens if the person has previously downloaded the app. If they have never downloaded the app before they will get the "this application requires iOS 8.0 or later" message.

Comment: Here is a workaround: [Switch iTunes account](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201248) to one that has downloaded this older version in the past, then download the app (will get the message above), then switch back to the original iTunes account (you will not be able to upgrade this App, which is not relevant in this case anyhow).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a better way:

Use another iOS 8 iPhone to switch iTunes Store Apple ID:

Example the donor has a new iOS 8 iPhone. Log out donor Apple ID from iTunes store. Then log in using the receipient's Apple ID. Search for Find my iPhone app. If the iOS 8 iPhone has installed the app, uninstall it to make way for the "Get" process. As soon as it starts downloading, stop the process. There you have the receipient's Apple ID with the app bought.

Now the donor can log back in using own Apple ID in iTunes store and redownload the app.

Then the receipient can use his/her own Apple ID in iPhone 4 to download the app.

Both parties got what they want on their respective Apple ID and iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue setting up my son's iPhone 4.

The important bit is to have an iTunes account that you've used to download an app in the past (in my case, my account, since I've had my account since the iPhone 3G days.)

On the iPhone 4, go to Settings > iTunes and App Store > tap Apple ID > Sign Out

Then Sign in with the other account (ie my account I've had for years).

Then go to the App Store and when you try to download an app, it will give you the "Download previous version" prompt. So go ahead and download it.

And don't forget to sign out and sign back in with the newer account (ie my son's).